# Are there ways to work around the limitations of the Open Graph action story attachment caption template?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, captions

There are 3 specific limitations of open graph action attachment captions that I'm trying to work around.  I'm referring to the attachment caption that is configurable in the Action configuration page (e.g. https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<app-id>/opengraph/action_type/<action-type-id>).

1. I can't find a way to insert newlines or line breaks.  I'm guessing this is probably by design, but it seems like a reasonable thing to be able to do.
2. If the action can be applied to more than one object type, you can't use fields from either object in the caption template.  If you do, the caption "breaks" (displays incorrectly) when you reference a field from an object that is unset.
   For example, action "drive" could be associated with "car" or "truck".  If the caption is `{car.model}`, then it breaks for trucks.  Related to [this post](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9386820/associating-open-graph-action-with-multiple-objects-caption-template). Ideally I'd like to be able to do something like `({car.model} OR {truck.make})`.
3. Optional action/object fields can't be used in the caption, because if they're ever unset, the caption "breaks" just as in #2 above.

When I say the caption "breaks," I mean that it displays incorrectly.  It seems to go into a debug mode where it displays `fieldName fieldValue` pairs for various fields from the object/action.

Are there any workarounds for these 3 issues?

Note that I'm not dealing with aggregations, just the actual action Open Graph post.

UPDATE: It looks like Facebook just pushed a change within the last day to allow multiple lines of caption.  That solves item #1.  Item #2 and #3 are still outstanding.

UPDATE 2: For #2, if you only put a single template item per-line (e.g. {someobject.somefield}), it seems to work OK. If that option is unset, that line doesn't display.  However, if you put more than one field, it seems to resort to the "breaking" behavior.  This might also work for #3, haven't tried yet.

Comment: Have you filed bug reports? I think I might be running into the same problems, but it's hard to tell when facebook isn't showing any of my action's captions. Not even the ones that contain no templates at all.

Comment: I've filed bug reports on this type of stuff in the past, but they just get ignored, so I've stopped wasting my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the updates above:

Facebook made a change to allow multiple lines of caption. That solves item #1 directly, and items #2 & 3 indirectly...

For #2 & #3, if you only put a single template item per-line (e.g. {someobject.somefield}), it seems to work OK. If that option is unset, that line doesn't display. However, if you put more than one field, it seems to resort to the "breaking" behavior. This might also work for #3, haven't tried yet.